# How to change the active of each controls in OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I  have [OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/NavToolbar-js.html) that is working fine.

[image]

But I need to unselect a PANTOOL and select the ZOOMTOOL instead.

Is there any function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `activateControl` method to choose control to active.

```
var navToolbar = new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar()    
navToolbar.activateControl(navToolbar.controls[0]); //will choose PANTOOL 

// If you want to choose another control. 
// Just change the index at navToolbar.controls[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
enter code here

// var bar = your_ol_control_navtoolbar    
bar.controls[0].deactivate();
bar.controls[1].activate();
```

hope, it helped

Comment: Thx but it doesn't work. The result is look like this http://i.imgur.com/O1c5eJX.png